# Collatz-like conjecture

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If integer $n$ is even do $n=n/2$, if odd do $n=2\lfloor{\sqrt n}\rfloor$. Doing this it eventually returns $1$. Why is that? For example, if we did $n=2n$ for odd $n$ it results in a loop, but the above not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, note that for $n \geq 3$, $2\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor < n$, so doing this for $n \geq 3$ forms a strictly decreasing sequence, eventually going to $\dots \to 2 \to 1 \to 2 \to 1 \to \dots$. Obviously this is no longer true if you do $2n$ instead.

Comment: Since $3n+1$ is not $<n$ it becomes a mystery why the collatz conjecture holds?

Comment: Yes, insofar as it means you can't make an argument as simple as this. Certainly you can say, pick the next to to be $n+1$ if $n$ is odd, and certainly $n+1 > n$, but it's pretty easy to show this goes to 1 eventually. In fact in this case since if $n$ is odd it progresses $n \to n + 1 \to \frac{n+1}{2} < n$, so in some sense Collatz is the first interesting $an + 1$ problem we can ask (since $2n+1$ blows up immediately).